# Push notifications are not received when app is not running

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

At least on a device running Android Jelly Bean (4.2.2) the push notifications are only received if the app is running. I think I'm doing everything right, that is, Im calling Parse.initialize on an Application class (which is referenced on my application tag on the manifest) and I have Parse's PushService and My custom Parse's Push Broadcast Receiver declared on the manifest just like this:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

<receiver android:name=".ParseCustomPushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I didnt force quit my app or anything else, for the matter.

I would like my app to always receive push notifications even when is not running, much alike what happens with popular apps such as WhatsApp, Facebook, Skype, etc.

I know I'm not the first one experiencing this problem because I've seen countless posts on several forums of people complaining of Parse push notifications not being received when the app is not running, but none of the answers to those posts offer a workaround...

So, can anyone explain why this even happens?? Is it an Android bug? Is it because Parse's PushService is not sticky? If yes, then, should not it be sticky???

And if possible, please, suggest a workaround for this problem! :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how exactly Parse library works but you should be sure that all permissions described here https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client is correctly described in your manifest file. I'm talking about  "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE".

Comment: Thanks Samik for the comment. Maybe I should've mentioned on the question that, yes, I'm using all those C2D/C2DM permissions

Comment: You get this sorted? I may have an explanation.